# HTTP probing utility

Tags: networking, web-server, network-monitoring

Looking for a probing utility that will periodically issue HTTP request and somehow provide an output (CSV/UI) on web server / network response times.

Nice to have: JavaScript-parsing ability to fetch all the referenced resources (images/css/scripts) altogether with the primary HTML file.

Preferably something that can be executed on Windows.

Looking for the utility, *not* network service - all will be applied on the intranet.

*Update*: till now found only [this](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/http-ping/) simple utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with [httping](http://www.vanheusden.com/httping/)? In combination with a little bit of code from your favorite scripting language (*ahem* Perl!) it will easily accomplish your goals.

If you're looking for something that is a little prettier give [Smokeping](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/) a try. You can use the Curl or HTTP [probe](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/probe/index.en.html) to specifically query your webserver for latency information. 
Smokeping is primarily designed for running on a Unix platform but some adventurous [souls](http://dev.pulsed.net/wp/?p=31) have managed to get it working on Windows.

[Pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com/) is probably the most polished service out there to do this. I've never used it so I can't comment on it efficacy, but it seems well liked by the folks here on SF. If I recall, the cost is pretty reasonable for the basic level service.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know about JavaScript-parsing. It is a hard question.

At least wget can download page with referenced resources and has win32 version.

Comment: Agreed - short of automating a GUI browser (which is resource intensive and prone to a large number of GUI event handling issues) there is almost no way of automatically handling javascript on webpages - this is common knowledge amongst the testing community - and is predominantly the reason why image sites are littered with javascript - to attempt to prevent scripters from harvesting images from their website.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something running on another server....

There are several commerical packages that can do what you want....but they cost.  One I like is HP's Sitescope.  Can't remember if the package runs on Windows or not, but the package would be resident on a seperate machine.   This package allows you to relatively easy script a session (like login/do stuff/logout).

Where I work now, I used nagios as my monitoring system, it does have facilities to check on specific URIs.  Nagios has limited abilities in performing a session monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a periodic scheduled request of a perl script with curl to actually issue the HTTP request?  You could use perl to pull timer information before and after the request and then push the difference between the two times to a database, where your web server could source the data.

Once you hit the Javascript piece all of that code is local execution anyway, so you will need to figure out if you need the server time or the complete end user experience time, which will vary from client to client depending upon what is going on with the client PC.

HP Business Availability Center will allow you to run QuickTest Professional Scripts as GUI Virtual User sampling agents which would give you the full browser experience, but there is certainly a cost to obtain that information.   SiteScope can give you the time minus JavaScript for the download items.    Both BAC and SiteScope can be implemented on an all Windows infrastructure.